Is it truth or not truth that Aristotle might not have written the lecture notes that are so important for philosophers?

Surviving fragments of the many lost works of Aristotle were included
in the fifth volume of Bekker's edition, edited by Valentin Rose.
These are not cited by Bekker numbers, however, but according to
fragment numbers. Rose's first edition of the fragments of Aristotle
was Aristoteles Pseudepigraphus (1863). As the title suggests, Rose
considered these all to be spurious.
(source: Wikipedia).

Aristotle's lecture notes are as important to modern philosophy as the Bible to Christians. But in both cases, from a philosophical point of qualification, can we say it is TRUTH or NOT TRUTH?  Do we have philosophical qualities like UNDETERMINED?

Maybe we could come up with our own ideas instead of searching for works lost 2000 years ago?

@ScottRowe - You can tell it to Christians or Jews or Muslims. For them, the older the knowledge, the more truthful it is.

The wine and cheese model of knowledge :-) I guess they're not big on computers or space exploration.

@ScottRowe Gurdjieff enumerates the 4 factors that determine all human issues: 1. mother-in-law 2. digestion 3. John Thomas 4. Cash. In less slangular language 1. relations 2. health 3. sex 4. finances. Have these essential human concerns changed at all in the last 2.5 millenia? I'd be interested in seeing that news!!

To "Matrix": Aristotle-IANISM is of course important to (western) philosophy. I don't see how that translates to Aristotle the person being central to philosophy. For all we know the guy who wrote 'Aristotle' may not be Aristotle. Just as the starting five books of the bible not be the creation of the figure IN those books called Moses. So???

And @ScottRowe: I believe Galileo was adamantly skeptical about the moon affecting the tides. Do you class Galileo along with Aristotle as unscientific? IOW between 2.5k years Aristotle and 500 years Galileo,Newton etc why privilege 500 over 2500? By human age standards both are a bit old dont-cha-think?

@Rushi seafood is best fresh, wine and cheese improve (up to a point) with age. All of it becomes inedible after eating. How do we have our truth and eat it too?

True @ScottRowe. I guess we have to live our truth(s)? I may derive inspiration from Aristotle 2 millenia ago or Kurt Vonnegut 20 years ago. Bur I cannot skimp on living my own life!

The authorship of Aristotle's works has been a subject of scholarly debate, with proponents of both early and late authorship views. On the contrary, it's a dynamical area of research, I'll try to give a birds-eye view here.  But first I'd like to comment the problem.
On the Aristotelian Noumenon.
We can never know what exactly the essence of Aristotle was, we always have to read his texts through the filter of an era, a culture.
A basic term like Eudaimonia can refer to a Daimon that was a power of some God, to a "good spirit" or to a motivation, depending on the culture of the time.
Starting from the very term God, which in Greek polytheism was just the inflection of Zeus, a completely different concept from what is understood by God throughout a historical process of abstraction.
What has been written
Wolt states that there is no clear consensus among scholars about the dynamic authenticity of the Magna Moralia.  (Wolt, 2021). Many texts we have today appear to be class notes from Aristotle's students, such as the two Ethics, which appear to be two notes from the same course, perhaps given on different occasions. Kenny (2016) suggests that some works attributed to Aristotle may have been written by a late student based on courses taught by Aristotle towards the end of his life (Wolt, 2021). This uncertainty surrounding authorship authenticity highlights the importance of authorship authentication in attributing texts correctly (Al-Ayyoub et al., 2017).
Kirby (2022) brings an interesting view about MM (I recommend reading his paper):

The authorship of the Magna Moralia (MM) is one of the great unsolved
mysteries of the Aristotelian corpus. There is a variety of views
about where the work came from, which can be roughly divided into two
camps. The first, which I shall call the early authorship view, holds
either that the work was written by Aristotle or one of his students,
perhaps as notes from a lecture course. On this The authorship of the
Magna Moralia (MM) is one of the great unsolved mysteries of the
Aristotelian corpus. There is a variety of views about where the work
came from, which can be roughly divided into two camps. The first,
which I shall call the early authorship view, holds either that the
work was written by Aristotle or one of his students, perhaps as notes
from a lecture course.

In the realm of authorship authentication, various methods and techniques have been developed, such as using classifiers and features for verifying the legitimacy of authors in text, which can be particularly relevant in addressing security concerns in online social networks (Li et al., 2016). Additionally, the use of learning models and statistical analysis has been proposed to authenticate authors and their writings (Taha et al., 2021).
The concept of authenticity in authorship extends beyond just verifying the author of a text; it also involves understanding the interconnectedness of perceptual and non-perceptual features in relation to authorship and authenticity (Selleri, 2013). This complexity is further compounded by the evolving nature of authorship in the digital age, where issues of attribution and ownership are becoming increasingly important (Rabbianty, 2023).
In the context of ancient texts, like those attributed to Aristotle, the challenge of authenticating writings is not unique. Scholars have grappled with similar issues in works like those of Julius Caesar, emphasizing the importance of robust methods for authorship verification (Kestemont et al., 2016). These methods often involve analyzing linguistic and computational characteristics of texts to determine authorship (Iqbal et al., 2013).
Overall, the authenticity and authorship of texts, especially those of historical significance like Aristotle's works, require meticulous analysis and scholarly rigor to ensure accurate attribution and understanding of the origins of these texts.
Bibliography
Al-Ayyoub, M., Alwajeeh, A., & Hmeidi, I. (2017). An extensive study of authorship authentication of arabic articles. International Journal of Web Information Systems, 13(1), 85-104. https://doi.org/10.1108/ijwis-03-2016-0011
Iqbal, F., Binsalleeh, H., Fung, B., & Debbabi, M. (2013). A unified data mining solution for authorship analysis in anonymous textual communications. Information Sciences, 231, 98-112. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.ins.2011.03.006
Kenny, Anthony. (2016). The Aristotelian Ethics. A Study of the Relationship between the Eudemian and Nicomachean Ethics of Aristotle. 2nd ed. Oxford.
Kestemont, M., Stover, J., Koppel, M., Karsdorp, F., & Daelemans, W. (2016). Authenticating the writings of julius caesar. Expert Systems With Applications, 63, 86-96. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.eswa.2016.06.029
Kirby, John, T., (2022). Authorship, Authenticity, Authority: Evaluating Aristotle’s Rhetoric and Poetics. Rhetorica-a Journal of The History of Rhetoric,  doi: 10.1525/rh.2022.40.2.111
Li, J., Chen, L., Monaco, J., Singh, P., & Tappert, C. (2016). A comparison of classifiers and features for authorship authentication of social networking messages. Concurrency and Computation Practice and Experience, 29(14). https://doi.org/10.1002/cpe.3918
Rabbianty, E. (2023). Ai in academic writing: assessing current usage and future implications. Insania Jurnal Pemikiran Alternatif Kependidikan, 28(1a), 14-35. https://doi.org/10.24090/insania.v28i1a.9278
Selleri, A. (2013). Authorship, authenticity and the perceptual/non-perceptual divide. Journal of Literary Theory, 7(1-2). https://doi.org/10.1515/jlt-2013-0007
Taha, A., Khalil, H., & El-Shishtawy, T. (2021). A two level learning model for authorship authentication. Plos One, 16(8), e0255661. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0255661
Wolt, D. (2021). Energeia in the magna moralia. Mnemosyne, 76(1), 65-94. https://doi.org/10.1163/1568525x-bja10079

A model answer we should all, if we can, emulate.

Thank you for pointing out the rich and deep field of textual analysis. The original question is unaware that since at least the 19th century (my limit of familiarity) the attempt to piece together and properly decipher ancient texts, has been an extraordinarily robust preoccupation of numerous disciplines including archaeology, philosophy, linguistics, and theology, to name four. The original question is surely easily and deeply satisfied somewhere therein!

@PaulCanis - To dedicate hundreds of careers and thousands of papers to satisfy someone's religious beliefs does not sound like useful science.

@TheMatrix Equation-balance -- The history of science begs to differ! Nietzsche's genealogical method prohibits foreclosing on the utility of an activity or thing having counter-intuitive outcomes. Surely you know this. Archaeology at first was spurred by the passionate fantasies of religion and oriental exotic myths. So, that is a stained science now? You have an incorrect view of how the past relates to the present when it comes to questions of empirical knowledge. You assume a privileged vantage point. Mistake.
